# In react-player, how can I disable the FullScreen button?

Tags: reactjs, react-player

This is my current code for rendering the react-player videos

```
<div className="player">
                    <ReactPlayer url={result.url}
                                 playing={false}
                                 width={275}
                                 height={150}
                                 onPlay={playVideo}
                                 onEnded={stopVideo}
                                 onPause={pauseVideo}
                                 controls={true}
                    />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the `controls` property to `false`, but it might hide some controls you didn't want to.

If your url is for example a Vimeo url, you can try to do something like this:

```
<ReactPlayer
   url='http://vimeo.com/...'
   vimeoConfig={{ iframeParams: { fullscreen: 0 } }}
/>
```

If it is a youtube url try this:

```
<ReactPlayer
    url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFJZ0HaYYB8'
    config={{
        youtube: {
             playerVars: { modestbranding: 1 }
        }
    }}
/>
```

Have a look on [this](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/issues/560) page, it might help as well, or in the [official component page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) under the **Config prop** section :)

Comment: I tried setting controls to False, but now it is bringing a "Youtube" watermark, which can be clicked and a tab change occurs!

Comment: But thanks a lot the official component page has exactly what I am looking for. It's the 'fs' tag

Answer (score 1):

```
<ReactPlayer
      width={"100%"}
      height={"100%"}
      url="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"
      muted={true}
      playing={true}
      controls
      config={{
        file: {
          attributes: {
            controlsList: "nofullscreen",
          },
        },
      }}
    />
```